# How to make predictions from the rolling regression module in statsmodel?

Tags: python, time-series, regression, statsmodels, rolling-computation

I have two sequences `(x_t, y_t)` in time and would like to perform a perform rolling linear regression. The problem in my mind is that:

- Given a window size `w`, compute `y` the time `t` based on the linear combination of `x` within time window (t-w,...,t,...t+w). That is, `y_t = sum_{i=t-w}^{t+w} b_i x_{i} + b_0,`

So I would like to fit the constants `b_i` using my data.

1. Is `statsmodels.regression.rolling.RollingOLS` the correct package to do that?
   The problem is that it only gives me the predict values and parameters along the same time axis, i.e., `y_hat_i` and `b_i` for each `t`. Instead, I would like to have a small set of `b` that I can use it for `x` data at other time `t`.

Comment: It's better if you stick to one question at a time and provide the code you've written so far. This way, the community could see the effort you've put and guide you through the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the right package. However, the regression coefficients will vary a lot, however you can smooth them by taking moving averages (of the coefficients), and then sampling from the moving averages.

Comment: how do I get the fitted parameters? they seem to be of length N_time rather than N_window...

Comment: As they should be. When you do a regression, you get 2 parameters, no matter how much data.

Comment: Interesting, my intended equation is different then? see my first bullet point in the question. Say, I set w=5, I have a 11 sample of `x` and that's 12 parameters (`b`'s).